# Saving and Clearing output file

Tags: linux

A process on Linux outputs file log.txt , I would like to save the contents of log.txt to new file and and clear the contents of log.txt everyday.

I can do this manually by using  by making copy  cp `~/temp/log.txt ~` and then clear the content of log file by  `touch log.txt`... but ideally i would like a process which does it automatically every day and saves with content to new log file with date.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at logrotate, it is quite configurable.

http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html